# Reduce gas price?

Tags: transactions, gas, uniswap, gas-price, cpp-ethereum

I'm working on a sniping bot on uniswap, and i have a little problem : the first ones to buy are those who pay the most. Pretty logical, but I don't really want to pay 300$ in priority gas to be the first one to buy 50$ of a token.
It's not that much the gas price, but more the priority gas which can be really high to be the first one. I was wondering if there were any way to still buy really fast without paying that much.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: It's uniswap v2 btw